# How can you update an NSMenu while it is active (visible)?

Tags: cocoa, background, nsmenu

I have an `NSMenu` instance, through which all communication with the Cocoa app will take place. If the menu is open, the background doesn't run, so how can I force an update while the menu is still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Force NSMenu (nested submenu) update for Main Menu of Cocoa App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232476/force-nsmenu-nested-submenu-update-for-main-menu-of-cocoa-app) and run that method in the background. (Don't forget to create an `NSAutoreleasePool`.)