# NSComboBox horizontal scroll

Tags: objective-c, horizontal-scrolling, nscombobox

Is it possibile to set an horizontal scroller to an `NSComboBox`? I've tried `wraps`, `scrolls` or `truncates` but they don't allow the horizontal scrolling. I have an `NSComboBox` that displays a long line of text (longer than the `NSComboBox` lenght) and it could be very useful to scroll the text.
Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't imagine scrolling horizontally in one of those. I would think your better option would be to just make it wider. Or consider using an `NSPopUpButton`

Comment: it's impossible to make it wider. `NSPopupButton` it's not good because:
"Note that while a menu is tracking user input, programmatic changes to the menu such as adding, removing, or changing items on the menu is not reflected."
And I need this functionality.

Comment: Here's some conversation on updating the `NSMenu` while it's open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232476/force-nsmenu-nested-submenu-update-for-main-menu-of-cocoa-app

Comment: What's your purpose for this? It might be better to use a `NSTextField` and an `NSTableView` if it gets too complex

Comment: I don't understand why you linked that conversation. I only wanted to know if is it possible to set an horizontal scroller to an `NSComboBox`.

I don't need `NSMenu`, `NSPopUpButton`, `NSTextField` or `NSTableView` or else.

Comment: Then your answer is no, which is why I'm trying to give you alternatives.

Comment: ok, "no" is an answer :) Unfortunately there's no alternative for me to NSComboBox. Thank you for the help